# Replace name of key(dot) in a json file(Time series)

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I'm trying to import some time series data in a MongoDB database, but it's not possible to have a . in a key name I get this error message:

> InvalidDocument: key '1. open' must not contain '.'

So how do I transform this json file:

```
({'2022-01-14': {'1. open': '171.3400',
   '2. high': '173.7800',
   '3. low': '171.0900',
   '4. close': '173.0700',
   '5. volume': '80440780'},
  '2022-01-13': {'1. open': '175.7800',
   '2. high': '176.6200',
   '3. low': '171.7900',
   '4. close': '172.1900',
   '5. volume': '84505760'},
   ...}
```

So that it's accepted by mongodb, so remove all the . from the key names such as 1. open

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

```
datadict = {'2022-01-14': {'1. open': '171.3400',
   '2. high': '173.7800',
   '3. low': '171.0900',
   '4. close': '173.0700',
   '5. volume': '80440780'},
  '2022-01-13': {'1. open': '175.7800',
   '2. high': '176.6200',
   '3. low': '171.7900',
   '4. close': '172.1900',
   '5. volume': '84505760'}
   }

eval(str(datadict).replace('. ', ' '))

{'2022-01-14': {'1 open': '171.3400',
  '2 high': '173.7800',
  '3 low': '171.0900',
  '4 close': '173.0700',
  '5 volume': '80440780'},
 '2022-01-13': {'1 open': '175.7800',
  '2 high': '176.6200',
  '3 low': '171.7900',
  '4 close': '172.1900',
  '5 volume': '84505760'}}
```